# Thawing frozen turkey slices

Tags: freezing

This is something I've planned on trying but haven't wanted to spend the $ for experimentation.

Buying sliced turkey for lunches at the deli is a tad pricey. At my local market I can get frozen turkey breast for a much better price per pound. But, the turkey breasts are 3+ pounds, and my household would use ~ 1# a week.

I figure I can just get a turkey breast, roast, make slices, and freeze a couple of batches for upcoming weeks. So, for the question. Do turkey slices thaw out ok in terms of texture and taste?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For short term freezing they should be just fine as far as texture and taste are concerned. Just make sure you avoid freezer burn by wrapping them tightly in plastic wrap and then either aluminum foil or a freezer bag. If you store them more than a few months then they will start to degrade.

Comment: Heh. It won't be stored for more than 3 weeks at most.